# C# struct to byte array marshal resulting in 19 elements instead of 20

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, udp, marshalling

A UDP server and client are running and do not show any error in compiling or running except after giving it more than 20 characters. Then suddenly I have only 19 characters returned on the server side.

It looks like the `SizeConst` of the string has actual dimension `-1`.

When I send strings it works until I get a string longer then 20 characters. It only keeps 19 charactars eventhough `SizeConst = 20`. (and when 3 it's only 2 chars, etc..)

**Can someone please explain why I suddenly am missing some data?**

```
/******************** STRUCT *****************************/
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TEST
{
    public string Buffer; 
    public int     number;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
    public string  aString;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
    public byte[] innerTestArray;
}


/****************** CLIENT ********************************//
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Start ServerSide acknowledge
        byte[] resp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("INIT");
        sendData(resp);

        while (true)
        {
            TEST test = new TEST();
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("ReadLine : ");
            test.aString = Console.ReadLine();
            test.number = 10;
            test.innerTestArray = null;
            test.Buffer = null;
            byte[] arr = structToBytes(test);
            sendData(arr);
        }
    }

/**************** MARSHAL FUNCTIONS *************************/
static byte[] structToBytes(object str)
{
        byte[] arr = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(str)];
        IntPtr pnt = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(str));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(str, pnt, false);
        Marshal.Copy(pnt, arr, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(str));
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pnt);
        return arr;
}

static TEST structFromBytes(byte[] arr)
{
        TEST str = new TEST();
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.Copy(arr, 0, ptr, size);
        str = (TEST)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, str.GetType());
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return str;
}


[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
```

In this example I allocated `20` as `SizeConstant` for the String. But when I receive the string it has a `SizeOf(string) = 19`.

Also it would be nice to have a more flexible approach for the string and other arrays so that there is much more flexibility. I.E. not to use the `SizeConst` within the struc. As in this example I only have some small data, but later on I have quite some difference in data to be send. List and arrays of structs and different datatypes.

**Any TIPS, TRICKS, IDEA's??**

PS: DEMO CODE at https://github.com/ritskes/C-UDP-struct-to-byte-DEMO-with-server-and-client

Comment: that repo is empty...

Comment: Personally, I try hard to avoid anything involving `Marshal` - it almost always isn't actually necessary or helpful in understanding what is going on; what is `Test` here? can we see `Test`?

Comment: You haven't shown any of your send/receive code; if the payload received doesn't **exactly** match the payload you think you are sending, nothing else will work - so the first thing to check is what is sent vs what is received. The easiest way to show that is `Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(yourByteArray))` - and compare the hex dumps

Comment: Yeah tried uploading both repos to github, but it failed. The Client is uploaded and can be found. And also the server seems now in another repo. Github is new to me. And it behaves different then I expected. But there is code now, but in 2 new repos instead.

Comment: Reason for having Marshalling is so I can send a STRUCT directly into a byte[] as UDP delivers the message by means of a byte[].

Comment: Or do you have any other way to have a struct into a byte[]

Comment: absolutely! options: "unsafe" (pointer thunking from `Foo*` to/from `byte*`), "spans" (`MemoryMarshal.Cast<TFrom,TTo>`), "unions" (in this case probably not useful as you'd need to use a `byte*` which just makes it the same as "unsafe"), and possible `ref` thunking - I need to see whether `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` has a "cast" method

Comment: if you're using "C# latest", a stackalloc'd span of length 1 might be trivial: `Span<Foo> foo = stackalloc Foo[1]; foo[0] = value; MemoryMarshal.Cast<Foo,byte>(foo).CopyTo(theArray);`

Comment: As far as I have seen there is no way to have a struct converted into a byte[] without using strict memory allocation. Would be great to have a generic function that allows you to send a struct and have it returned in a byte[]. As far as I know that is today not possible without strict SizeConst or other memory allocation [MAX size etc..]. As a struct can also include pointers to other array's or lists or even other structs. (Background: C++ code to be translated C# which is managed and C++ is unmanaged, guess that this is the main issue here??)

Comment: Span<Foo> foo = stackalloc Foo[1]; foo[0] = value; MemoryMarshal.Cast<Foo,byte>(foo).CopyTo(theArray);  Do you have an example with current struct as specified above?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because [the interop assumes that the string will be null-terminated, hence the marshalling is adding a null terminator](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings.md). This means that the longest the string can be is 19 characters allowing for the null terminator.

(Note that the documentation doesn't actually state that `ByValTStr` will add a null-terminator - but it does!)

The following compilable console app demonstrates the issue:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Demo
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct TEST
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
        public string aString;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            TEST test = new TEST();

            test.aString = "1234567890123456789012345";

            int    size = Marshal.SizeOf(test);
            byte[] arr  = new byte[size];

            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(test, ptr, true);
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);

            Console.WriteLine("Bytes: " + string.Join(", ", arr));

            test = Marshal.PtrToStructure<TEST>(ptr);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

            Console.WriteLine(test.aString); // Prints "1234567890123456789" - only 19 characters.
        }
    }
}
```

The solution may be to use a char array instead:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Demo
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct TEST
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
        public char[] aString;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            TEST test = new TEST();

            test.aString = "1234567890123456789012345".ToCharArray();

            int    size = Marshal.SizeOf(test);
            byte[] arr  = new byte[size];

            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(test, ptr, true);
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);

            Console.WriteLine("Bytes: " + string.Join(", ", arr));

            test = Marshal.PtrToStructure<TEST>(ptr);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

            Console.WriteLine(new string(test.aString)); // Prints "12345678901234567890" - all 20 characters.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I expected, so this confirms my testresults. So either have a MAX of 21 (if I want 20) or use your CHAR example.  Super THANKS!

Comment: Is it possible to noty have a MAX allocation for the char[] so there is no restriction (not using SizeConst. (of course I will try some stuff myself as well with different data. As this was just to see if UDP can handle structs

Comment: @Ritskes Not sure what you mean about the max allocation... The array must be the same size as the `SizeConst` specification, I think. If you want to make a smaller string from the char array that you get back, you could search the array for a NUL value and then you'd know how long to make the string.

Comment: What I ment is: to have the lenght of the original string (longer then the max size due to strict allocation in the struct) to be assiged as full lenght in the struct on a flexible way. Would it be possible to have the marshal code for the struct to have a variable assigned towards the SizeOf inside the struct? (i meant Size Const)

Comment: Heres another observation I had while working with this. In using a struct with any string properties annotated by SizeConst I noticed you can initialize the struct with a string exceeding the defined length.  But when you convert to bytes and then back, the string will be trimmed corresponding to the SizeConst if it exceeded the length (including the null terminator).  This puts me in the char[] camp for readability and maintainability.  Alternatively, you can set the SizeConst = DesiredLength + 1 as noted, and then validate or trim in the constructor against the DesiredLength